# Timeout handler implementing Callable does not throw Exception

Tags: java, exception, timeout, callable

I have the following two classes

```
public class TimeoutHandler
{
  private int timeoutMsec = 10000;
  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
  private ScheduledFuture<String> future;

  public TimeoutHandler()
  {
  }

  public TimeoutHandler(int msec)
  {
    timeoutMsec = msec;
  }

  public void startTimeoutHandler() throws TimeoutException
  {
    scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    future = scheduler.schedule(new TimeoutCallable(), timeoutMsec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class TimeoutCallable implements Callable<String>
{
  @Override
  public String call() throws TimeoutException
  {
    throw new TimeoutException();
  }
}
```

Now I start the `TimeoutHandler` with the method `startTimeoutHandler()` and it should schedule a future thread to start in `timeoutMsec`. The problem is, that the `TimeoutCallable` is never called and the `throw new TimeoutException();` is never launched. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We will need to call `future.get()` to retrieve the result and this function will throw the exception if provided as a `ExectuorException`: the cause can be retrieved invoking the `getCause()` on the exception as shown below:

```
     try {
          future.get();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(CallableTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getCause());
          //Logger.getLogger(CallableTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
```

**Output:**

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Comment: And when to call future.get()? If I startTimeoutHandler() I do some socket communication and if e.g. nextLine() does not respond the TimeoutException should be thrown.

Comment: I guess `future.get()` should be called in the `nextLine()` function. As your callable has the result type `String`, The result can also got by the `future.get()` function too.

Comment: The thing is, that nextLine() on InputStream is a blocking call. So I need the TimeoutHandler to throw the Exception automatically.